# Elasticsearch - Trouble querying for exact date with range query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following mapping definition in my events index:

```
{
  "events": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "properties": {
            "reportDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "M/d/YYYY"
            }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And an example doc:

```
{
    "_index": "events",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "12345",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 90,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "data": {
            "reportDate": "12/4/2018",
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is query for docs with an exact data.reportDate of 12/4/2018, but when I run this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "data.reportDate": {
                "lte": "12/4/2018",
                "gte": "12/4/2018",
                "format": "M/d/YYYY"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I instead get all of the docs that have a data.reportDate that is in the year 2018, not just 12/4/2018. I've tried setting relation to CONTAINS and WITHIN with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your date format from `M/d/YYYY` to `M/d/yyyy`. Refer to this [ES official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats) to know more about date formats. You can even refer to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) to know about the difference between `yyyy` and `YYYY`

> yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of
> “Week of Year”)

Adding a working example with index mapping, data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "properties": {
          "reportDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "M/d/yyyy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "reportDate": "12/3/2018"
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "reportDate": "12/4/2018"
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "reportDate": "12/5/2018"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "data.reportDate": {
            "lte": "12/4/2018",
            "gte": "12/4/2018"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65312594",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "data": {
            "reportDate": "12/4/2018"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Matt E did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Hi @ESCoder - thanks for your answer! Working on another problem this morning, but will give your solution a shot in a few hours!

Comment: Sure @Matt E looking forward to get update from you 

Comment: @MattE its been a long time. I hope you are doing well  Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @MattE if my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept it as well 

Comment: Hey @ESCoder, sorry just got around to trying out your solution, everything worked! Thanks for the help